# How Node handles intensive file operations with only few threads in Thread pool?

Tags: java, node.js, threadpool, event-loop

I understood how Node uses operating system's de multiplexer to make non blocking calls asynchronous and it handles all requests in a  single thread by saving huge memory costs  associated by avoiding to create million threads(one for each client).It also helps developers approach concurrency in applications much simpler way.All is well so far.

The trouble starts for me when thread pool comes into picture.its given in node documentation that wherever operation system's demultiplexer support is not good then node uses thread pool(which is nothing but threads ,4 by default and 128 max) to achieve similar functionality.It also mentions file operations use thread pool instead of OS's demultiplexer.

So my concern is let's say I am writing a web server that needs to complete few file operations per client then if a million of clients are using my application  at a time  then Node's 4 worker threads may take forever to serve all the requests as Node's thread pool can work on four file operations at the moment by default. others have to wait till those threads are free.Even considering best case of Node 's thread pool 128 threads may not be  better considering say Tomcat which can process million file operations in parallel  in blocking mode.

This made me thinking if web server has too many IO operations(mostly file and db related),is Node really the right choice?

Comment: The idea that Node uses operating system's demultiplexer to make non-blocking calls asynchronous and it handles all requests in a single thread by saving huge memory costs associated by avoiding to create a million threads(one for each client) is enough i think

Comment: Thats broad idea but https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/on-problems-with-threads-in-node-js/ points out how threadpool affects the perofrmance of the application.So the above question makes me wonder if I didnt understand Node fully? or Node is not suitable for intensive file operations?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, one of the primary ideas behind Node.js is that you should design your server application so that the storage or retrieval of persistant, mutable state data gets defered as quickly as possible to some other system.

If you do that, you can then cluster multiple instances of node processes on the same computer or different ones, each of which runs your code.

As a result, you gain a far greater degree of scalability than can be possible with a single monolithic process, no matter what technology it's implemented with.

This concept is what gives Node.js its name. Each process should be a node in some cluster.

I don't know about yourself, but I wouldn't want to re-implement and mix the capabilities of an enterprise data storage solution into my business logic as there are developers who focus on nothing but the issues involved and its unlikely most application developers could do as well as them.

Have you actually tested whether there's a performance issue though? If not, how do you know there's any issue at all? Most files may only be open for a short time perhaps.

On a technical level, there is a limit to the number of files which Node.js can open simultaneously. After that level is reached, file operations will fail with an EMFILE error (too many open files). To exceed this amount there's a Node.js module you can use https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs that enqueues further file operations.

Comment: I havent done any testing.My question was just to know ..how node handles intensive blocking  file operations per each client with just 4(or 128 max)threads?

Comment: It's as you say, it will use the OS's demultiplexer support or a thread pool otherwise. My point is that you probably need to rethink how your application is architected if you're worried by the size of the thread pool. This would still need to be done even if you prefer to use Tomcat. Although Tomcat may be able to have open 1 million files, the HTTP response to each user may take longer than with Node.

Comment: in documentation its mentioned that when OS demultiplexer support is not available then thread pool comes into picture.Yes I know ,that Node is preferred when more IO operations are involved,but I am just wondering how?